# jquery attr('title') a tag

Tags: jquery, title

`enter code here`i use: jquery-1.6.2.min.js

i want to get the content of an a tag -->> title <<-- attribute

example html code:

```
    <div id='menu1' class="menu">
      <a class="dock" href='#' title='some text bla bla 001'><img src='http://www.linktoimage.com/sample.jpg' /></a>
   </div>
```

inside document ready function i use this jquery code:

```
    $(function(){
    $('.menu a').click(function(){
         alert($(this).attr('title'));
        // $('.headline').empty();
        // $('.headline').append('<p>'+ $(this).attr('title') +'</p>');
    });
});
```

problem:

alert only returns undefined

can someone help? thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
alert($(this).attr('title')); 
return false;
```

after you click on the link the browser reloads, you need to return false to prevent it

Comment: even better than returning false is executing event.preventDefault() (where 'event' is passed into the click function).

Comment: Greg is right. Further, `.attr()` is appropriate for the title.

Comment: The location change of the browser does not take place until after the alert, so it would not explain what the OP says they see. Not to mention that the code the OP gave actually works fine.

Answer (score 2):

It works. See my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/STN9j/

Answer (score 0):

`.attr()` is proper for a title attribute, and your example code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/z2zFe/